# SQL Trigger to Update a Record instead of Inserting if values havent changed

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

Im trying to implement an SQL Trigger that will UPDATE instead of INSERTing if the value of one column hasent change..

### Example Table

```
Id | Name | Income | Date
11   John   10000    2019-02-01
11   John   15000    2019-02-02
```

This table does not have a Primary Key, because it will have multiple records for the same ID, each one with a diferent date. What I want to achive to save some space is to UPDATE instead of INSERT if the Income hasent changed... for example, if the next record is going to be:

```
11  John  15000  2019-02-03
```

I want the trigger to UPDATE the DATE instead of creating a new Record on the Table. So it will end up like:

```
11   John   10000    2019-02-01
11   John   15000    2019-02-03  <-- Changed!
```

The data comes from an hourly table that records the incomes from the day... and at the end of the day does a massive insert of all records on the hourly table to the incomes table to keep the history.

I tried the following trigger but it did not work since it does a lock.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_income
    BEFORE INSERT ON income_30
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.income = (select income from income_30 where ID=NEW.ID and date=(select max(date) from income_30)) THEN
        UPDATE income_30 set date = NEW.date where ID=NEW.ID;
END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

I also though about doing an UPDATE instead of INSERT and perform a trigger that will do the opposite, will insert a new record if the income changed, but I didn't know which column could I make primary for the update.

I Apologise if it is a silly question, but its being bothering me for a while.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about saving space I think you should only delete last month with the same income record just before you try to insert new income, with same amount.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_income
    BEFORE INSERT ON income_30
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.income = (select income from income_30 where ID=NEW.ID and date=(select max(date) from income_30)) THEN
       DELETE FROM income_30 where id=NEW.id and date=(select max(date) from income_30);

END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Not particularly sure you can modify the table the trigger is attached to from the trigger.

Comment: Thanks, but It crashes when I perform an insert, I think its like what @Shadow says...

Comment: cant update the table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger @EmreSERBEST